# Angular asynchronously loaded variable not updated in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to get asynchronousity working in angular, but it's not quite working yet. But almost.

I've tried to condense down my code to the bare minimum:

```
<div ng-controller="GeoSelectController">
    <div>
        Select country:<br/>
        <select multiple required size="10" ng-model="geoFilter" ng-options="geo.name as geo.descr for geo in geos"></select>
        <p>You selected {{geoFilter}}.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customModule.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    var cm = customModule();

    app.controller("GeoSelectController", function ($scope) {
        //some starting values.
        $scope.geos = [
            {name: "DE",  descr: "Germany"},
            {name: "NL",  descr: "Netherlands"}
        ];
        $scope.geoFilter = ["NL"];

        //asynchronously get actual values.
        cm.doAsync("nrg_100a", function(error){
            if (error) {alert(error); return;}
            $scope.geos = cm.getSomeData("nrg_100a", "GEO");
        });

    });

</script>
```

The problem here is the `cm.doAsync()` part. What happens is that the `geos` variable *is* updated, but *it is not shown in the view* until the select box is being clicked. I have recorded a screencast to clarify:

[image: update]

(If I click the already selected 'Netherlands', the select box's options are not even updated at all.)

I've tried putting the whole thing inside a factory, but to no avail, and I don't think it's necessary either. If you think this is key though, than please explain why this is so; I'll be more than happy to post the code that also fails.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Try adding $scope.apply() after the $scope.geos assignment.

Comment: if the async function is not using one of angular's services it does not create a digest cycle. You will need to start one, [$scope.apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), in the callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most possibly because `doAsync` is not running in angular scope. Meaning `digest` cycle is not happening after work is done. You can work around this by using `$scope.apply()` to manually force the digest cycle and to have the bindings updates.

```
    cm.doAsync("nrg_100a", function(error){
        if (error) {alert(error); return;}
        $scope.geos = cm.getSomeData("nrg_100a", "GEO");
        $scope.$apply(); //<--- here
    });
```

If it is doing an async operation (and custom module is something you can change), you can make use of promise pattern using angular version of [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and you don't need to do this step. If you are doing something an http call you could use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and chain through the promise, and the bindings will be automatically updated once the promise is resolved/rejected.

Create a service to wrap your non angular service:-

```
MyService.$inject = ['$q', '$window'];

function MyService($q, $window){

   this.getGeos = function(value1, value2) {
        var def= $q.defer();
        var cm = $window.customModule();
        cm.doAsync(value, function(error){
            if (error) {
               def.reject(error); //<-- reject the promise
            }
            var value = cm.getSomeData(value1, value2);
            def.resolve(value);
        });
      return def.promise;
   }
}

angular.module("myApp").service('MyService', MyService);
```

And use it as:-

```
app.controller("GeoSelectController", ['$scope', 'MyService',function ($scope, myService) {
    //some starting values.
    $scope.geos = [
        {name: "DE",  descr: "Germany"},
        {name: "NL",  descr: "Netherlands"}
    ];
    $scope.geoFilter = ["NL"];
    myService.getGeos("nrg_100a", "GEO").then(function(result){
        $scope.geos = result; //set the result
    }).catch(function(error){
       alert(error); //Handle Error
    })
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @PSL for your quick answer. I'm reading into the promises a bit, is there a way to build a wrapper for a method that requires a callback, so that it returns a promise instead?

Comment: @ElRudi Absolutely... You can create a service that wraps this and inject that service.. Do you need an example?

Comment: If you have one at hand, that'd be awesome. I've found several examples in node, and/or using Q, but I haven't found any using `$q` which is necessary in AngularJS, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ElRudi Updated my answer. Havent tested so not sure of any typos

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly, thanks!
Just so I understand: (1) why do you pass `['$scope', 'MyService', function()]` to `app.controller()`? I've used only the `function()` and it works too. (2) Why the `var cm = $window.customModule();` in the `MyService`? It works without as well.

Comment: @ElRudi it is dependency injection, it has been added for testeability. Just to explicitly say that customModule is a part of window